# How to install a certificate for a website in IIS 7+ and make https optional?

Tags: iis, ssl, ssl-certificate

How do you install a certificate for a website in IIS 7+ and make the use of https optional?

Ideally, we would like http to be the default and then for specific pages use an https URL.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't a programming question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, just point to url without https://

And here's a tutorial.  http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis